# Get a list of network connections my machine is making

Tags: networking, connection

On Ubuntu, how do I get a list of network connections my computer has made in the last few days? Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: for future cases, you can set up your system as described in [there](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcpip-connection-monitor-howto/).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can't get ended connections unless you were logging them.
To get the current connections:

```
# sudo netstat -tupn
```

This will show the current opened source and destination ports with IPs.

To get more details about the contents of the connections, install tcpdump if it's not installed and run:

```
# sudo tcpdump -X -i eth0
```

And you can run that in the background and write the output to a file.

Comment: Thanks @islam. Is there is a good way to automatically convert the ip address in netstat to their corresponding dns entries?

Comment: In the netstat remove the argument 'n' which means don't resolve IPs to hostnames.

Comment: I would recommend adding the -a (all) flag as well.

Comment: sudo netstat -tupnc  <-- added c for continuous if you need to watch it for live connections.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loooking for a list of ports you can use:

```
netstat -tupn | grep -E ":(22|80|8000) .*"
```

or

```
netstat -tupn | grep -E ":(22|80|8000) .*ESTABLISHED"
```